# java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission

Tags: android-permissions, android-bluetooth, samsung-mobile, android-12

After asking for runtime permission for BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, android 12 crashes , I faced this problem in Samsung Android 12 Device. In other device less then Android 12 is working fine.

I handled bluetooth permission but still my app going to crash

> manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

> sdk -> 31

Showing this type of error after build the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

As you can see the BLUETOOTH permission is disabled in Android 12. This issue resolved if I add the maxSdkVersion for the BLUETOOTH permission.
So I update permissions in manifest file :

Old This:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

to

new this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" android:maxSdkVersion="30"  android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30"  android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Is this solution scalable for the future?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yes this solution is scalable for the future